# Influx aggregation query return wrong time

Tags: time, precision, aggregation, influxdb

I'm a new influxdb user and my influxDB version is 1.7.1. I have problem with time in influx.

I have a measurement called lv_table, Listing_id and event_type are tags and event_id is field

```html
select *  from "lv_table" limit 10 
name: lv_table
time             Listing_id event_id event_type
----             ---------- -------- ----------
1542711774019000 105202696  4        "leads"
1542711774020000 105497566  66       "view"
1542711774021000 95532296   66       "view"
1542711774021000 98830991   1        "leads"
1542711774022000 105456186  66       "view"
1542711774023000 94326731   66       "view"
1542711774025000 104584666  66       "view"
1542711774028000 105603346  66       "view"
1542711774035000 99913981   66       "view"
1542711774037000 105430516  3        "leads"
```

but when I use "precision RFC3339" in cli, that query return date in 1970 year like '1970-01-18T20:31:51.774019Z' but correct time is '2018-11-20T20:31:51.774019Z'

```html
> precision RFC3339
> select *  from "lv_table" limit 10 
name: lv_table
time                        Listing_id event_id event_type
----                        ---------- -------- ----------
1970-01-18T20:31:51.774019Z 105202696  4        "leads"
1970-01-18T20:31:51.77402Z  105497566  66       "view"
1970-01-18T20:31:51.774021Z 95532296   66       "view"
1970-01-18T20:31:51.774021Z 98830991   1        "leads"
1970-01-18T20:31:51.774022Z 105456186  66       "view"
1970-01-18T20:31:51.774023Z 94326731   66       "view"
1970-01-18T20:31:51.774025Z 104584666  66       "view"
1970-01-18T20:31:51.774028Z 105603346  66       "view"
1970-01-18T20:31:51.774035Z 99913981   66       "view"
1970-01-18T20:31:51.774037Z 105430516  1        "leads"
>
```

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

In aggregation query it gets worth ... and show time in 2016 but it should be in 2018-11-20 date

1468800000000000 = Monday, July 18, 2016 12:00:00 AM

```html
select count(*) as count_leads  from "lv_table" where "event_type" = '"leads"' and time < 1542745800000000 group by Listing_id,time(1d)
>...
name: lv_table
tags: Listing_id=99965506
time             count_leads_event_id
----             --------------------
1468800000000000 1

name: lv_table
tags: Listing_id=99965771
time             count_leads_event_id
----             --------------------
1468800000000000 2

name: lv_table
tags: Listing_id=99966146
time             count_leads_event_id
----             --------------------
1468800000000000 1

name: lv_table
tags: Listing_id=99966736
time             count_leads_event_id
----             --------------------
1468800000000000 3
...
```

If I don't use group by on time, time will be equal 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Influxdb stores timestamps internally as nanoseconds since Jan 1 1970, so your first datapoint is actually interpreted as:

`1542711774019000 ns -> 1542711 s -> Sun Jan 18 20:31:51 UTC 1970`

and this is what you see when use "precision RFC3339" in cli.

Not sure how you got

> 1468800000000000 = Monday, July 18, 2016 12:00:00 AM

`1468800000000000 ns -> 1468800 s -> Sun Jan 18 00:00:00 UTC 1970`

This is your first datapoint timestamp rounded to 1 day.

You didn't describe how your put data into table. In Influx HTTP API you can specify precision of input timestamp data with an optional query parameter (see [InfluxDB HTTP API reference](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/tools/api/#write-http-endpoint)).

`Precision` setting in influx tells how to treat input timestamp data. Timestamp value on input is always integer (not rfc3339 string). And this integer is interpreted according to precision setting.

> `precision=[ns,u,ms,s,m,h]    Optional    Sets the precision for the supplied Unix time values. InfluxDB assumes that timestamps are in nanoseconds if you do not specify precision` ([see Influx docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/tools/api/#write-http-endpoint) here)

It also affects output format for query result. See examples below:

```

```
> precision ns
> insert demo value="precisionNS TS treated as nanoseconds" 1543220939000000000
> precision s
> insert demo value="precisionS TS treated as seconds" 1543220940
> precision ms
> insert demo value="precisionMS TS treated as ms" 1543220940123
> precision rfc3339
> select * from demo
name: demo
time                           value
----                           -----
2018-11-26T08:28:59Z           precisionNS TS treated as nanoseconds
2018-11-26T08:28:59.123456789Z precisionNS TS treated as nanoseconds
2018-11-26T08:29:00Z           precisionS TS treated as seconds
2018-11-26T08:29:00.123Z       precisionMS TS treated as ms
> 
> precision s
> select * from demo
name: demo
time       value
----       -----
1543220939 precisionNS TS treated as nanoseconds
1543220939 precisionNS TS treated as nanoseconds
1543220940 precisionS TS treated as seconds
1543220940 precisionMS TS treated as ms
> 
> precision ns
> select * from demo
name: demo
time                value
----                -----
1543220939000000000 precisionNS TS treated as nanoseconds
1543220939123456789 precisionNS TS treated as nanoseconds
1543220940000000000 precisionS TS treated as seconds
1543220940123000000 precisionMS TS treated as ms
```

```

Comment: Thank Yuri, but when I convert 1542711774019000 to human readable time in "https://www.epochconverter.com/" site I get "GMT: Tuesday, November 20, 2018 11:02:54.019 AM" as a result that is correct time. you men that "precision RFC3339" first interpret "ns" to "s" ???

Comment: I use NiFi to insert data in influx. I create query like `lv_table,Listing_id=101510816,event_type="view" event_id="66" 1543041515116000` and "putinfluxdb" processor in NiFi insert this query to influx